# A question based on lower limit topology( 2nd countable, 1st countable)

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I had really terrible instructor for the topology course . So, I am trying exercises for this course of another Institute.

I need help in proving this question.

> Prove that lower limit topology is 1st countable but not 2 nd countable.

Please help.

Comment: Given a point $x\in\Bbb{R}_l$, can you find a countable neighborhood basis for this point?

Comment: This is also called the Sorgenfrey Line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Let $x\in\Bbb{R}_l$ there exists a neighborhood basis $\mathcal{N}(x)=\{[x,1/n):n\in\Bbb{Q}\}$ which is countable since $\Bbb{Q}$ is countable.
2. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be its basis, then for each $x\in\Bbb{R}_l$, $\exists U$ open s.t. $x=\inf U$ which implies $\exists B_1\in\mathcal{B}$ s.t. $x\in B\implies x=\inf B$. Similarly, if we choose another distinct point $y\in\Bbb{R}_l$, then $y$ corresponds to a basis element $B_2$ s.t. $y=\inf B_2$. Now this implies that there is a bijection obtained by restricting the range of the map $f:\Bbb{R}_l\to \mathcal{B}$ s.t. $f(x)=B_1$, $f(y)=B_2$ and so do all other point, so $|\Bbb{R}_l|\le|\mathcal{B}|\implies$ the basis is uncountable.

Comment: there is a typo in 4 th line of 2. . Rest is clear. Thanks!!